# How to hide the button when clicking other button using VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery

We have a requirement where the customer can sign and fill the form and submit.After submitting the form the form will be saved as a attachment and the form will be emailed to the Owner of the Account as a PDF. I have achieved all the above process. But I need two command buttons to achieve the whole process. In this case customer might get confused or there is a chance for their to miss any of the button , So I have an idea to avoid this, When the customer enter into the form they can see only one button called "Submit" after clicking the submit button the page should be reloaded with the other button called "Please Review and Confirm" then the submit button should be hidden. Then the user needs to click the button to complete the form. So can anyone please guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi Arun Use Disable Attribute in commandButton tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These Help Your Scenario[image] 
Visualforce page:

```
 <apex:page controller="Sample" sidebar="false">
    <apex:pagemessages />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Disable" disabled="{!disabl}" action="{!dis}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Controller:

```
public class Sample
{
    public Boolean disabl {get;set;}

    public void dis()
    {
        disabl = true;
    }
}




 ![Here is The Output ][1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. Can we hide the button instead disable using this code?

Comment: Keep your Button in <apex:outpanel render={!boolean}> and then you can hide it ,,sure it wl work out

Answer (score 2):

You can use apex:commandButton's either **onclick** or **rendered** attribute to set visibility of the button. First approach will hide the button on the client only, while second will not render the button at all:

The **onclick** approach:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!someAction}" value="Hide On Click" onclick="this.style.display='none';"/>
```

The solution with **rendered**  attribute would feature just an extension of Vineeth's approach:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="pnl1">
    <apex:commandButton value="Disable" action="{!dis}" rerender="pnl1" rendered="{!disabl}" />
</apex:outputPanel>
```