# Hide/Show Custom Button In Standard Detail Page

Tags: custom-button

[image: Email Button]

We have  custom  Email button on a Custom Quote detailed page. I would like to show the button Based upon the Quote field and Quote Line Field, Here Quote and Quote-line item both having master detail relationship, quote is parent. both objects having the UPDATE field when UPDATE=TRUE at that situation i have to show button remain cases hide the button.Is this possible and if so how do we do this?

Comment: is that a custom page designed with visualforce ?

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23859/how-to-hide-the-button-when-clicking-other-button-using-vf-page/23866#23866 see this post , let me know

Comment: @Vineeth i want to hide/show button when Field UPDATE=True this field is exist in Quote,Quote-line item.

Comment: ok ,use javascript to achieve that functionality

Comment: @Vineeth actually that button is created Buttons and Link section. shall i use Js for such of buttons.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13985/discussion-between-sathya-and-vineeth)

Comment: @Sathya -- this might also help - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13529/conditional-rendering-of-buttons-when-using-apexdetail-and-inlineedit-true conditional rendering of custom buttons on apex:detail component